# what is the xul file for the firefox "Edit this bookmark" Panel called?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul, firefox-addon-sdk, xpcom

okay, i need the xul file for the window which opens up when you try to bookmark a page in firefox,

i tried searching for `chrome://browser/content/bookmarks/bookmarksManager.xul.` 
But i get the following error

```
File not found

Firefox can't find the file at chrome://browser/content/bookmarks/bookmarksManager.xul.

Check the file name for capitalization or other typing errors.
Check to see if the file was moved, renamed or deleted.
```

i can view `browser.xul` and other files but this one seems to be missing, what should i be searching for?

this is the popup i want to create an overlay for
[image]

Comment: You mean the pop up panel in australis?

Answer (score 2):

In Australis the "Edit this bookmark" panel is created on runtime:
http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-aurora/source/browser/base/content/browser-places.js#1034

Comment: , i'm using Firefox Aurora 30.0a2, and i think there is supposed to be a file `chrome://browser/content/bookmarks/bookmarksManager.xul` if not how exactly can i create an overlay xul for that panel?

Comment: you have to add to it during runtime. what are you trying to do? ill give you demo script. the id of the panel is `editBookmarkPanel` so go `var panel = document.getElementById('editBookmarkPanel');` and then muck around in there. this code changes the label value: `panel.querySelector('#editBookmarkPanelTitle').value = 'rawwwr'`

Comment: are you sure there is no xul file?tried the code out, did'nt change the label value to 'rawrr', could you change "edit this bookmark" to simply "bookmark"

Comment: the code doesn't work because on popupshowing the stuff gets modified everytime. copy paste this code it will change the label: `var panel = document.getElementById('editBookmarkPanel');
panel.addEventListener('popupshown', function(e) {
panel.querySelector('#editBookmarkPanelTitle').value = 'rawwwr'
panel.removeEventListener('popuphiding', arguments.callee, false);
})`

Comment: i get `panel is null` error, i guess it's not recognizing the id "editBookmarkPanel"

Comment: hm thats weird are you running in browser environment from scratchpad?

Comment: that inline code is missing a semicolon use this: `var panel = document.getElementById('editBookmarkPanel'); panel.addEventListener('popupshown', function(e) { panel.querySelector('#editBookmarkPanelTitle').value = 'rawwwr'; panel.removeEventListener('popupshown', arguments.callee, false); })` i also remove it after one popup, so its not always there for demo puproses. for your real purpose you probably dont want that panel.removeEventListener within the function

Comment: thats real weird, yep coppy pasting that works. im using ff 30, do what @m.j.saedy recommended, get the element insepctor then shfit rightclick on the bookmark panel make sure all the ids are right

Comment: mm, this is how i ran your code, [xul window] with button, when i click the button it calls a function and runs your code. any different from what you did?

Comment: oh it works!, but only when i trigger it from the 'star' UI bookmark button. its strange that the id is not recognized when triggering it from an xul window.. on startup

Comment: i really need to add the event listener on startup, my extension looks like this, [tools]->[my_extension],  previously i tried to trigger it with a button inside [my_extension] and that did'nt work., could you tell me from where you called the function?

Comment: can you upload to github and link me ill look at the problem. i dont understand what you mean by triggering from xul window.

Answer (score 1):

There is no xul window, it is just a panel.

here is code to add a button to the bookmark panel (tested on Firefox 27, i don't know for 30):

```
let panel = document.getElementById('editBookmarkPanel');
//let lbl = panel.querySelector("#editBookmarkPanelTitle");
//if(lbl) lbl.parentNode.removeChild(lbl);
lbl = document.createElement('button');
lbl.setAttribute('label', 'Cool!');
lbl.setAttribute('id', 'foo');
lbl.setAttribute('oncommand', 'alert("foo")');
panel.appendChild(lbl)
```

BTW, to find out XUL window locations and almost anything else, install the following extensions: DOM Inspector (of course!) and [InspectorWidget](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/inspectorwidget/) and [Element Inspector](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/element-inspector/) the last two allow you inspect anything using a toolbar button or shift+RightClick.

Comment: i get `panel is null` error, i guess it's not recognizing the id "editBookmarkPanel"